# Excel's SUMIFS implemented using PANDAS, the Python Data Analysis Library

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I've implemented Excel's [SUMIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) using the following code. Is there a better — more Pythonic — implementation?

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# pandas equivalent of Excel's SUMIFS function
df.groupby('PROJECT').sum().ix['A001']
```

One concern I have with this implementation is that I'm not explicitly specifying the column to be summed.

### Data File

Here's an example CSV data file (`data.csv`), although I'm displaying | instead of commas to improve the visual appearance.

> ```
> DATE     | EMPLOYEE     | PROJECT | HOURS
> 02/01/14 | Smith, John  | A001    | 4.0
> 02/01/14 | Smith, John  | B002    | 4.0
> 02/01/14 | Doe, Jane    | A001    | 3.0
> 02/01/14 | Doe, Jane    | C003    | 5.0
> 02/02/14 | Smith, John  | B002    | 2.0
> 02/02/14 | Smith, John  | C003    | 6.0
> 02/02/14 | Doe, Jane    | A001    | 8.0
> ```

### Equivalent Excel SUMIFS Function

If I were to open `data.csv` in Excel and wanted to determine how many hours were worked on project A001, I would use the SUMIFS formula as follows:

```python
=SUMIFS($D2:$D8, $C2:$C8, "A001")
```

Where the [SUMIFS function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) syntax is:

```python
=SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2,
        criteria2], …)
```

Answer (score 5):

The usual approach -- if you want all the projects -- would be

```
>>> df.groupby("PROJECT")["HOURS"].sum()
PROJECT
A001       15
B002        6
C003       11
Name: HOURS, dtype: float64
```

This only applies the `sum` on the desired column, as this constructs an intermediate `SeriesGroupBy` object:

```
>>> df.groupby("PROJECT")["HOURS"]
<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0xa94f8cc>
```

If you're only interested in the total hours of a particular project, then I suppose you could do

```
>>> df.loc[df.PROJECT == "A001", "HOURS"].sum()
15.0
```

or if you dislike the repetition of `df`:

```
>>> df.query("PROJECT == 'A001'")["HOURS"].sum()
15.0
```

but I find that I almost always want to be able to access more than one sum, so these are pretty rare patterns in my code.

Aside: `.ix` has fallen out of favour as it has some confusing behaviour.  These days it's recommended to use `.loc` or `.iloc` to be explicit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do simple sum aggregation together with `SUMIF`, or multiple `SUMIFS` with different criteria simultaneously, I would suggest the following approach:

```
(
  df
  .assign(HOURS_A001 = lambda df: df.apply(lambda x: x.HOURS if x.PROJECT == "A001" else 0, axis=1))
  .agg({'HOURS': 'sum', 'HOURS_A001': 'sum'})
)
```

or without per-row apply (this version is much faster):

```
(
  df
  .assign(HOURS_A001 = lambda df: df.HOURS * np.where(df.PROJECT == "A001", 1, 0))
  .agg({'HOURS': 'sum', 'HOURS_A001': 'sum'})
)
```

So basically apply criteria and create a new row, then sum values in this row.